# google drive PHP permission

Tags: php, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client

I am want to share permission on some folders on google drive, with help google service account, but Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message 'Error calling POST https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0ByXNGBI2AHyZX0RZd2pROE5qNFk/permissions: (500) Internal Error' 
Its problem has been only when use Service Account type authentication

when i am paste more scopes`array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file'),`  i recive 404 error File not found 0ByXNGBI2AHyZX0RZd2pROE5qNFk

```
 <?php
session_start();
include_once "templates/base.php";

/************************************************
Make an API request authenticated with a service
account.
 ************************************************/
set_include_path("../src/" . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path());
require_once 'Google/Client.php';
require_once 'Google/Service/Drive.php';

$client_id = '1077677978854-deaidfbbb36erpstbjsvqh6s1iftg36k.apps.googleusercontent.com';
$service_account_name = '1077677978854-deaidfbbb36erpstbjsvqh6s1iftg36k@developer.gserviceaccount.com';
$key_file_location = './8c320ff616a77aec2421642de64449dad6f4a9ca-privatekey.p12';

$client = new Google_Client();

if (isset($_SESSION['service_token'])) {
    $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['service_token']);
}
$key = file_get_contents($key_file_location);
$cred = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
    $service_account_name,
    array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'),
    $key
);
$client->setAssertionCredentials($cred);
if($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion($cred);
}
$_SESSION['service_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
var_dump($client);
$service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);
$newPermission= new Google_Service_Drive_Permission();
$newPermission->setType('user');
$newPermission->setRole('reader');
$newPermission->setValue('rizr19911006@gmail.com'); //thats email to share
$service->permissions->insert('0ByXNGBI2AHyZX0RZd2pROE5qNFk',$newPermission);
```

Comment: I am facing this same problem (with service account authentication also).  I am making two calls to insert permissions, one specifically sets the owner and that works.  The other is changing visibility to public, unlisted (role = 'reader', type='anyone') and it is failing with a 500 error.  Even the API Explorer on the API page https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/insert fails (having granted permission via oauth) so it isn't a PHP API problem I think.

Comment: Have you confirmed that the service account has sharing permissions on that file already? This could be a case where there should be an error, but the message isn't a great one.

Comment: I am found reason of problem, I'm try share permission on directory which located on my personal(xxx@gmail.com) disk-drive, but service account have personal disk drive, that cause I'm recive error "file not found". First of all, I am created with help PHPcode(cause service account dont have UI) new directory on service account drive,than get id of directory, and share this directory to my general mail with writter's permission, where i can edit and add new files!

Answer (score 0):

You should manually share the file with the $service_account_name email address.